# Activity tab on profile: only the last retag is listed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, recent-activity

I've retagged a few questions on SO lately, but the [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22689?tab=activity#tab-top) only displays the last retag (as `revised`). That means that everytime I do a retag, the previous one just disappears.

Is that intended? Is that a bug? It seems that the behavior changes along with the reputation: I just have retagging rights, whereas users with editing rights do have a more detailed list of recent retaggings (see Jon Seigel's answer and comments).

Comment: Re your edit: Some of the posts that show up in my activity summary were *edited*, not just re-tagged. That may have something to do with it as well. I would imagine that edits would be less likely to group together; but on some of my big retagging sprees, I've edited as I went, and they've grouped together sometimes as well.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The recent activity page groups edits that are within a certain period of time, like when you go on a retagging spree. I'm not sure what the window is -- probably 5 or 10 minutes -- maybe Jeff can chime in here.</strike>

I just started on another retagging, but the questions are all over the map (going through the least popular tags), and all the edits are showing up on my activity page. So I think the revisions get grouped if the system detects you're revising questions with similar/overlapping tags.

In some ways, I'm glad the system does this (my activity page would be nothing but revisions), but at the same time, if I want to go back and review what I retagged, I have to use another method to do it.

Comment: I experienced the same and it's imo OK so.

Comment: I've just had another try to verify this, with completely different tags... "Activity" still restricts the list to the last retag. I guess I'll have to try again when I have edit rights...

Comment: @Raphael: Check out the activity on [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/164901?tab=activity#tab-top), and compare it to yours.

Comment: @Jon: oooh, nice case study. Well, I guess we could qualify it as counter-intuitive behavior, then.

Comment: @Raphael: Yeah. I'm hoping Jeff sees this question and gives the criteria for doing the grouping. That would clear up this issue quite a lot, as opposed to guessing.

Comment: Wait... What ? There are other methods to review what you retagged ?

Comment: Judging from your profile and those of a few other retaggers, it seems the grouping is solely on whether your edits were purely retagging in nature or not. Notice how no one ever has two entries in a row stating just "edited tags". I think it is mostly time independent, but if you give me a day, I'll see if my latest tag edit will just change instead of appending a new entry.

Comment: @ccornet: Yeah. Figuring out how some of the sorting/listings in the system works is kind of like an Enigma machine. I really wish Jeff or a developer would answer this question.

Comment: [This image](http://i.imgur.com/OXwsX.png) shows the results of the test. The last retag 24 hours ago was changing [3.0] to [wss-3.0] and [designer] to [sharepoint-designer], while the newest retag was just removing [strange]. There's no relation between tags, and it's unreasonable for a threshold that is higher than 24 hours, so I would say that the only thing that affects whether your activities are merged is if they were nothing but retags.

Comment: It seems like that 'Activity' tab is grouped by descriptions. I did a half dozen edits today (all with the same description), but only one is showing up.